# How to change the current working directory

Tags: python, pyinvoke

Using [invoke](http://invoke.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), how can I change the directory that the `run` call operates in?

In Fabric, one would

```
from fabric.context_managers import lcd
with lcd('foo'):
   local('do')
```

to run `do` in the `foo` directory, but I can't find a similar import in pyinvoke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Context.cd`

Take a look at [docs](http://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/latest/api/context.html#invoke.context.Context.cd)

```
with ctx.cd('/path/targeted'):
    # do something in /path/targeted
```

Answer (score 6):

as simple as that

```
import os
os.chdir(path)
```

Comment: No need to complicate things